# How to toggle the Tawk.to bot in flutter web?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-js-interop

I successfully integrated the Tawk.to chat bot in my flutter project by copying the script in my HTML body section.

I was wondering how I can toggle it in dart by clicking on a widget

I followed the documentation here https://help.tawk.to/article/using-a-text-link-or-button

in my flutter code I tried two methods

1. Calling the link using url_launcher package

   ```
   Future<void> toggleBot() async {

   final url = Uri.parse("javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())");
   if (!await launchUrl(url)) {
     throw 'Could not launch $url';
   }}
   ```
2. Using dart:js to call java script

   ```
   js.context.callMethod("window.Tawk_API.toggle()");
   ```

both of these methods do not work. what am I doing wrong? and how do I achieve what I am trying to achieve